Audio Preamp Design Feedback
I designed this simple pre-amp circuit for a piezo electric pickup.
I spun a PCB and built 2 boards up.
It works, but I wanted to get some feedback on the design.
Are there any apparent issues with the design?
The DC rail is from a 3.7V Lipo battery.
And I did a ground pour on the top and bottom to try to help with any external noise.
Are there any additional components or circuits that could be implemented to improve the performance. Mostly better signal to noise ratio, a way to handle clipping more gracefully, or any protection circuitry.
Thanks!



The TLV9061 has good noise performance at 10 nV per root Hz, but it's not the best available.  Your 1 Meg divider resistors are also decent thermal noise generators.  Could be fine, depending on your SNR requirements.

The divider resistors don't matter for noise. But maybe use 10 Meg instead, to make absolutely sure they don't load the piezo. Also place a small cap across R4, a few 10s of pF, because having a 100k feedback impedance at high frequencies can make opamps oscillate.

All the capacitors in your design, which you seem to have chosen arbitrarily, require more careful consideration. They all cause a delay prior to settling at the DC operating point, which you should aim to minimise with careful calculation of the cut-off frequency. While the calculations below are correct, there's a caveat which I'll address later.
Input impedance is \$R_{IN}=R_1\parallel R_2=500k\Omega\$, which in combination with C1 makes a time constant of \$R_{IN}C_1=5s\$. Following an input connection, the op-amp output will instantly saturate, which is normal, but will take at least this many seconds to return to its DC operating point, and amplify linearly.
\$C_1\$ forms a high pass filter with \$R_{IN}\$, and its value should be chosen to produce a cut-off frequency in keeping with the audio spectrum. For instance, if you wish to keep all frequencies down to 20Hz, choose a cut-off frequency well beyond that, say 10Hz:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f &= \frac{1}{2\pi C_1R_{IN}} \\ \\
C_1 &= \frac{1}{2\pi fR_{IN}} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \times \pi \times 10\rm{Hz} \times 500k\rm{\Omega}} \\ \\
&\approx 33\rm{nF}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using this value, all frequencies in the audio spectrum are passed, and DC voltage settles in \$33\rm{nF} \times 500\rm{k\Omega}=0.17\rm{s}\$ or so.
\$C_3\$ and \$R_5\$ are another high-pass filter, and \$C_3\$ should be chosen to exhibit similar cut-off frequency, and time constant:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_3 &= \frac{1}{2\pi fR} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \times \pi \times 10\rm{Hz} \times 100k\rm{\Omega}} \\ \\
&\approx 150\rm{nF}
\end{aligned}
$$
Caveat: often the equipment sourcing the input signal, and anything connected to the output, will have its own impedance and capacitance in series, which will raise cut-off frequency. C2 isn't subject to this, since you control its peripheral resistors. It's therefore generally a good idea to use capacitors greater than those calculated above, by a factor of 3 or more, so I'd suggest:
$$ C_1 = 100\rm{nF} $$
$$ C_3 = 1\rm{\mu F} $$
The value of \$C_2\$ is less trivial to establish, because cut-off frequency is dependent upon a varying resistance \$R_7\$, which I assume has a maximum value of 500kΩ. Before I address \$C_2\$, though, I'll talk about the position of \$R_7\$.
Gain of this circuit is:
$$ A = 1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_7} $$
It has a maximum at \$R_7 = 0\$:
$$ A = 1 + \frac{100\rm{k\Omega}}{100\rm{\Omega}} \approx 1000 $$
Minimum gain occurs when \$R_7=500\rm{k\Omega}\$:
$$ A \approx 1 + \frac{100\rm{k\Omega}}{500\rm{k\Omega}} \approx 1.2 $$
A problem becomes evident if you calculate gain when the potentiometer is positioned 10% along its travel (I'm ignoring that it's a log pot), with a resistance of \$R_7=10\% \times 500\rm{k\Omega}=50\rm{k\Omega}\$:
$$ A \approx 1 + \frac{100\rm{k\Omega}}{50\rm{k\Omega}} = 3 $$
This tells us that gain changes between 3 and 1000 over only 10% of the potentiometer's physical range, and the remaining 90% is responsible for between 1.2 and 3. I am certain that you would like a more linear relationship between potentiometer position and gain.
This occurs because the gain-setting resistance \$R_7\$ appears in the denominator of the gain expression, and you have gain \$A\$ roughly proportional to the reciprocal \$\frac{1}{R_7}\$. The solution, of course, is to place \$R_7\$ where \$R_4\$ is currently:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This puts \$R_7\$ in the numerator, so that gain \$A\$ has a roughly proportional relationship with \$R_7\$:
$$ A = 1 + \frac{R_7 + R_3}{R_4}  $$
To illustrate, at the half-way point \$R_7 = 250\rm{k\Omega}\$, you have a gain of roughly half the 1000 maximum:
$$ A = 1 + \frac{250\rm{k\Omega} + 100\rm{\Omega}}{500\rm{\Omega}} \approx 500 $$
Now we can calculate C2, for a cut-off frequency of 10Hz. This frequency is dominated by R4:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_2 &= \frac{1}{2\pi fR_4} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \times \pi \times 10\rm{Hz} \times 500\rm{\Omega}} \\ \\
&\approx 33\rm{\mu F}
\end{aligned}
$$

There are a few more issues. With a gain of 1000 you must consider these:

Gain bandwidth product of the TLV9061 is 10MHz. At maximum gain (1000) the closed-loop bandwidth of your amplifier will fall to \$\frac{10\rm{MHz}}{1000}=10\rm{kHz}\$. It will begin attenuating well below that, which is not ideal for an audio system.

The input offset of the TLV9061 can be as bad as 2mV. This will be multiplied by closed-loop gain, so the DC output level will be severely offset from the center-point you desire. It could be offset as far as \$1000\times 2\rm{mV}=2\rm{V}\$, in either direction.

The input noise of the TLV9061 is \$10\rm{nV/\sqrt{Hz}}\$, which is too high for an audio amplifier. At maximum gain, output "hiss" will be awful. The easiest solution for this is to use op-amps with better noise specifications, although lower value resistances everywhere will also help.


Number 2 is the biggest headache you have. Unless you employ an op-amp with input offset in the microvolts, this can only be overcome by splitting the amplifier into two lower-gain stages, and AC coupling them. For instance, two stages with gain 32 with provide overall gain of \$32^2\approx 1000\$. Conveniently, that would also solve issue 1, the bandwidth problem, since each stage will now have much improved individual bandwidth. It also means that you can use a much lower-spec op-amp (in bandwidth terms), which has its own benefits.
Typically we would use a higher gain first stage, using a more expensive audio-grade op-amp (for low noise), AC coupled to a lower gain second stage, for which noise and offset is no longer such a big deal. Since many op-amps comes in pairs in the same package, there's no harm in using a really nice op-amp, twice.
Also, you might like the potentiometer to get down to zero-gain, so that it behaves more like a standard volume control. One way to do that uses the potentiometer in the feedback path for an inverting stage:

simulate this circuit
The first stage has a fixed gain of approximately 100, so a 2mV input offset only produces a 0.2V output offset, much more acceptable. Since this stage will introduce the most noise, you would choose the best op-amp in this respect.
The second stage inverts, and its gain is adjustable between \$-\frac{0}{R_5}=0\$ and \$-\frac{500\rm{k\Omega}}{R_5}\approx -10\$. With such low gain, you aren't so concerned with noise or offset, and any old op-amp will do.
If you want the entire spectrum of audio frequencies to be amplified equally, then you would require the first stage op-amp OA1 to have gain-bandwidth product somewhat in excess of \$100 \times 20\rm{kHz}= 2\rm{MHz}\$, and for OA2 over \$10 \times 20\rm{kHz}= 200\rm{kHz}\$.

Thanks for the post it was super enlightening. I went ahead and updated the design to use an audio grade op-amp OPA1611AIDR and the MCP1801T-3302I_OT. I also changed the caps to all film, minus a single 100uF electrolytic bulk cap on the front end.

Sorry grabbed the wrong part number for the second op-amp. It's a TLV9151QDCKRQ1. The 22uF film cap is relatively large, do you think it could be changed out for a electrolytic, or maybe an electrolytic with a smaller film cap in parallel?

@Feloria An electrolytic one is fine

tlv9061 definitely is not audio grade. Noise is high, and THD is also not very good.
What is type of capacitors C1/C2/C3 ? Non polar, likely X5 or X7? Don't, distortion level would be not acceptable. Try electrolytics, better ultra /low leak current specified.
And some resistor on the non-inverting input of OPA to limit current (470 Ohm - 1k) in case if input jumped to V+ or ground.

C1,C2,C3 couple audio .Avoid microphonic ceremac caps here .Metal film would be better .They will use more space .If you can raise the supply volts and do a split supply your dynamic range will improve .Class A jfet input opamps sound very good .Battery life will be worse .You can soft clip across R4 with resistor diode matrix or bilateral square law scheme to remove the sharp distortion rise on overload .
